# Using extract() with flag EXTR_SKIP to prevent security issues

Tags: php, security, extract

I am using extract to get all the values of a form sent by POST and save them in different variables.
My doubt is if using extract() with the flag EXTR_SKIP is the 'best way' to prevent security issues, like (maybe?) overwrite values of the form and other security issues that I don't know (My knowledge about web security is quite limited)

Comment: Why do you want to use that instead of dealing with the `$_POST` variable as is?

Comment: @Jon because I have a lot of inputs and I always like to learn the fastest way, to be more productive (obviously being aware of security)

Comment: This, I don't believe, is the solution you would want for that. `register_globals()` was turned off automatically for a reason. ^^ It is best to deal with it while it is still in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays. Doing so also means that when looking through your code, you know what is strict user input, and if you do move it to a normal variable, you'll know by briefly looking whether or not you have sanitized it as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a lot of inputs and I always like to learn the fastest way, to be more productive (obviously being aware of security

Optimize for being able to read quickly, not being able to write quickly.

But if you really want to go down this route:

```
<?php    
// Important, ONLY allow the indices you really want to support
$whitelist = array_key_whitelist($_POST, [
    'foo',
    'bar', 
    'baz',
    'moo',
    'usr',
    'lol'
]);
// Then run extract() as expected
extract($whitelist, EXTR_SKIP);
```

And the function is, of course:

```
<?php
/**
 * Only allow the whitelisted array keys to exist:
 *
 * @ref http://stackoverflow.com/a/36193403/2224584
 * @param array $input
 * @param array $allowedKeys
 * @return array
 */
function array_key_whitelist(array $input, array $allowedKeys = []): array
{
    $return = [];
    foreach ($allowedKeys as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $input)) {
            $return[$key] = $input[$key];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

This is marginally safer than `extract()` with `EXTR_SKIP` in the context of a loop where, in the future, variables might not get set to their sane values if they were already defined.

But seriously, this is more of a code golf nicety than a practice you should *actually* follow.